# Understanding Autoencoder Loss

Tags: math, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function, autoencoder

I'm trying to grasp the loss of an Autoencoder and I'm rather confused about it. In the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) article about autoencoder, the loss is defined as [image] where [image] is a reference probability distribution.

I'm trying to understand the following:

1. What does reference probability distribution means in this context?
2. What is the notation E_{x~μ_{ref}} and especially what does the E term denotes?
3. How is this loss function different from the loss of a variational autoencoder where the probability distribution error is getting minimized?

Comment: This is a statistics question, you should ask it in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ , not in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

An autoencoder is trained for data compression. The loss function measures the success of the encoder-decoder process in reconstructing the compressed input. The measure for this is the mean squared error between the encoder input and the decoder output.

In your equations, the encoder is denoted as `E_phi` and the decoder `D_theta`.

> What does reference probability distribution means in this context

Think of it this way, if the input doesn't have a probability distribution then it's just noise. Having a probability distribution suggests that there is a pattern to the data. The purpose of the autoencoder is to attempt to reconstruct the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by examining the equation below

[image]

The notation [image] is the parameter of the decoder [image], while the notation [image] is the parameter of the encoder [image].

The goal of the autoencoder is to minimize the difference between the original input image [image] and the reconstructed image  [image].

Hence,the notation [image] is the function to measure the dissimilarity between [image] and [image].

Typically, we train an autoencoder to address a specific problem, such as reconstructing dog images, cars, or MRI scans. Thus, the reference probability distribution [image]  represents the real-world distribution we aim to reconstruct, and  [image] is  lies within this distribution.

For instance, when reconstructing dog images, we gather real-world dog images and train an encoder [image] and a decoder [image]  to encode these images into a low-dimensional space and decode them back into dog images.

During training, we sample real-world dog images, akin to [image] - we sample a real world image  [image], from the reference probability distribution [image]. However, as we have a lot of real-world dog images, we employ the expectation  [image]  to compute the average loss value.

Variational Autoencoders (VAEs) are a different story, but you can think of VAEs as minimizing two distributions, while autoencoders minimize two data or images. Using dog images as an example again, VAEs aim to generate 'fake' dog images by learning a distribution that approximates the real-world dog image distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is still not clear to me what the notation E_{x~μ_ref} is. Since d(x, x') is the "distance" between original and reconstructed input does E_{x~μ_ref}[d(x, x')] mean the expected "distance" between original and reconstructed input where the original follows a distribution μ_ref?